# Changing values that can be selected in combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a ComboBox that looks like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboTest"
    FontFamily=

... //set the font, style, size, etc.

<ComboBox.ItemBindingGroup>
    <BindingGroup/>
<Combobox.ItemBindingGroup>
<ComboBoxItem Content="1"/>

... // range is from 1 to 27
```

The range of values I can select from the ComboBox is from 1-27. However, I want to have a config file that I can read from to change this range. How can I do this?

Comment: Bind ComboBox.ItemsSource to an `ObservableCollection<T>` property of your viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int num = Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["num"]);
cboTest.ItemsSource = Enumerable.Range(1, num);
```

...and put this `<appSetting>` in your `App.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6"/>
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="num" value="27"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

You need to add a reference to `System.Configuration.dll`. Project->Add Reference->Assemblies->Framework in Visual Studio.